# In a REST api, what is the downside of having state information, or information targeting the resource, in an http request header?

Tags: rest, http-headers, resources

In a REST api, what is the downside of having state information, or information targeting the resource, in an http request header?
(As opposed to having state information in the request body or url, and the information targeting the resource in the url.)

If so, why?

If not, why?

These are my thoughts:

- resources should be targeted by the URL-path
- state-change information should be in the request body or the URL-path.
- headers are meta-data, and should
  not be used to identify the resource or the state
- for GETs, caching proxies only cache the URL, so if part of the resource description is in a header, the header information will not get cached, resulting in bad cache data
- Query strings should contain meta-data about the request, for instance, paging information